# Enter text into an EditText which then disappears when user clicks inside it

Tags: android

I would be very grateful if someone could explain if it is possible to enter text into an EditText. (This would be done with  `android:text=""`)

But then the text would disappear when user clicks inside it.

Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This can be done by using hint:

```
android:hint="the text you want"
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the `android:hint=""` attribute .. it is removed when the edittext is clicked on

**EDIT:** I was too late :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also set an OnClickListener for your EditText just as you would for a button and in the onClick() method call editText.setText(""); But simply using android:hint as mentioned above is going to be easier and work just fine if that is the only work you need done when the user clicks on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio v3.0.1 you can click on your XML page's TextView field, then you will see right corner is opened (Attributes), you can see at the bottom (all attributes), and find "Hint" section to type what you wanted to see to be get disappeared later. This is my solution, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

this is because you haven't set its inputType.